# What am I missing from my inventory?

Tags: candy-box-2

I have finished the game, but I've got a gap in my inventory:

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purple fin. You can obtain it the same way you got the other fins. Just keep going in the sea until you find the purple finned shark.

You'll probably need the pink gloves and unicorn horn to survive that long, but you already have those. It'll appear roughly around the point where there's 2 sea snakes and 3 sharks on screen at any one time.